# Shell cmd "date" without new line in the end

Tags: shell, newline

I want to output a line of date using date command, but it's end with a "\n" which I don't need it, currently, I use:

```
echo -n `date +"[%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"`
```

or

```
date +"[%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"|tr -d "\n"
```

Are there any built-in parameter for "date" to do that?

Comment: Hey novice3; can you select an answer?

Comment: @Bamboomy Or the new user should specify in a comment somewhere, how all the answers are falling short, in case he's looking for something that none of us are considerating.

Answer (score 33):

No there isn't. You need another command like `echo -n`, `printf` or `tr`. You could put a script somewhere in your PATH (eg. /usr/bin/) and make it executable with `chmod +x /usr/bin/mydate`

script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n `date +"[%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"`
```

or use an alias.

```
alias mydate="echo -n `date +"[%m-%d %H:%M:%S]"`"
```

Answer (score 30):

Bash **printf** does not require **date** to work:

```
printf '%(%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T'
```

will output the current time without a newline.

Comment: For older bash versions you have to add "-1" value at the end. Like this: `printf '%(%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T' -1`

Answer (score 17):

You can use **printf**. It doesn't add new line symbol:

```
$ printf `date "+%d.%m.%Y"`
22.01.2016$
```

Comment: You should prefer to use a format string for printf: `printf '%s' "$(date "+%d.%m.%Y")"`

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to replace the newline with some form of space so output doesn't run together.

Full example which can be used to monitor peak size of a workspace:

```
nohup watch -t -n 60 "(date '+%F/%H:%M:%S' | tr '\n' '\t'; du -sh /folder/to/monitor/) >> workspace.log" &
```

Don't forget to kill this as the file would grow indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add something after date in each line.
Instead of using date without EOL you can do it other way around.
Inside date command you can add ouput of any other command by using $() or backticks ``.
Final output is the same, date and then something in each line.

For example:

```
date "+%F %T $(echo 123)"
```

will print date and then 123 in same line.