# Ansible ad-hoc command: How to return command runtime in output from host?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, ansible

I am running a simple Ansible ad-hoc command across all hosts in inventory and I want Ansible to also show the time it took to return output from each host. I can see the time in log, but I want to have it as `stdout`.

I tried adding `callback_whitelist = profile_tasks` in `ansible.cfg` but that did not help.

For example, Ansible command

```sh
[demo@demoserver ~]$ ansible all -m shell -a 'hostname -f'
```

output shows

```yaml
worker0 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
iworker0.unix.demo.com

worker2 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
iworker2.unix.demo.com

worker1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
iworker1.unix.demo.com

worker3 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
iworker3.unix.demo.com
```

and log shows

```yaml
2020-01-30 15:46:27,924 p=22811 u=demo |  worker0 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
iworker0.unix.demo.com

2020-01-30 15:46:27,955 p=22811 u=demo |  worker2 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
iworker2.unix.demo.com

2020-01-30 15:46:27,960 p=22811 u=demo |  worker1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
iworker1.unix.demo.com

2020-01-30 15:46:27,975 p=22811 u=demo |  worker3 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
iworker3.unix.demo.com
```

So, I want the time from log to appear as `stdout` as well. Is that possible?

```sh
[demo@demoserver ~]$ ansible --version
ansible 2.7.12
  config file = /home/demo/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/demo/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Jun 11 2019, 14:33:56) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

Comment: I would not know a straight forward way to do it. All I can think about is using playbooks instead of ad hoc, so you can use "profile_tasks". Other option, again, not exactly what you are looking for, is to use the command time "ansible all -m shell -a 'time ; hostname -f'. Lastly, in case you have an ELK, you could use it to parse those logs and get that info...not in "stdout" but you would get it. Sorry, this is all I can think of.

Comment: Tried that earlier...result is a 'non-zero return code' for 'time ; hostname -f' and 'time && hostname -f'. btw, what is ELK? never used before.

Comment: Elasticsearch Logstash Kibana stack. Know is known as "elastic stack". Too complicated to implement only for that purpose. I'm curious now about that "non-zero return code". I'll try it tomorrow when I'm on my pc again :)

Answer (score 0):

In respect of your requirement

> *I want Ansible to also show the time it took to return output from each host*

and comment

> *Tried that earlier ... result is a `non-zero return code` for `time ; hostname -f` and `time && hostname -f`*

the command

```sh
ansible test --user ${ACCOUNT} --ask-pass -m shell --args 'TIMEFORMAT=%R; time hostname -f'
```

is just working and producing an output of

```yaml
test.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
test.example.com
0.003
```

In respect of of your requirement

> *I want the time from log to appear as `stdout`*

which doesn't show the time it took to execute the command but the datetime, you could add a timestamp after the command as follow

```sh
ansible test --user ${ACCOUNT} --ask-pass -m shell --args 'date +"%T.%3N"; hostname -f'
```

and which is producing an output of

```yaml
test.example.com | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
12:34:56.789
test.example.com
```

or

```sh
echo -n `date +"%T.%3N"` " ";  hostname -f
```

for an output of

```yaml
12:34:56.789 test.example.com
```

**Credits To**

- [How to get `time` with milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548528/)
- [How to get just real time value from `time` command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795634/6771046)
- [Shell cmd `date` without newline in the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942796/)

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible ad-hoc output: How to split every node result with new line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70228752/6771046)